# How to update a column in temporary database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I need to update a column from a temporary database created in mySQL. I've tried to change the variable but it's not work. Here's my script:

```
$sid=md5(time());//new value
mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_2 SELECT * FROM prop_itinerary WHERE prop_sid = '$_GET[sid]'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tmptable_2 SET prop_sid ='$sid'");//this is where I need to change the prop_sid from the original 'prop_itineraty.prop_sid'
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO prop_itinerary SELECT * FROM tmptable_2");
mysqli_query($con,"DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_2");
```

When I print out `UPDATE tmptable_2 SET prop_sid ='$sid'` it turns out the `$sid` correctly. But still when it inserted into DB it is a `sid` from `prop_itinerary.prop_sid`.

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to all `mysqli_query()` see if it returns any errors.

Comment: You could be getting duplicate key errors when you try to insert.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I've got an error `Duplicate entry '210' for key 'PRIMARY'` @Barmar Yes, I've got an error!

Comment: Is having a PK important? If not, then remove it.

Comment: It's not important for the `insert` but `update` and `delete` will cause a problem. :(